# complex Eigen::VectorX return view to either real or imaginary part

Tags: c++, c++20, eigen3

I have an `Eigen::VectorX<std::complex<RealType>> x` and depending on some parameter I want to return either `x.real()` or `x.imag()`. I don't want to return this as a `Eigen::VectorX<RealType>` since that operation would require heap allocation and it would be sufficient to return some kind of view, since the storage of `x` can be considered as persistent.

Is there any way to return a light weight view in both cases? Unfortunately, `x.real()` and `x.imag()` have different return types. My current solution is to pass a `Eigen::VectorX<RealType>& x`, which at least prevents the unnecessary heap allocation, but still an unnecessary copy operation.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a strided map, with the first element pointing to the first real or first imaginary value (untested code):

```
template<typename RealType>
using RealOrImagView = Eigen::Map<const Eigen::VectorX<RealType>, Eigen::Unaligned, Eigen::InnerStride<2> >;

// double can be a template parameter, of course
RealOrImagView<double> foo(const Eigen::VectorXcd& input, bool real)
{
    return RealOrImagView<double>(reinterpret_cast<const double*>(input.data()) + (!real), input.size());
}
```